Galois group of $x^{3}-x+1$ over a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$
Question. Let $F$ be a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $E$ be the splitting field of $x^{3}-x+1$ over $F$. Compute the Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(E/F)$.
Attempt. Let $F=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, and let $K$ be the splitting field of $x^{3}-x+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $E=K(\alpha)$. It is easy to show that $x^3-x+1$ is irreducible modulo 2, hence it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Since $\Delta=-4\cdot(-1)^3-27\cdot(-1)^2=-23$ and $\sqrt{-23}\notin \mathbb{Q}$, then $\mathrm{Gal}(K/Q)=S_{3}$, consequently, $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=6$.
Note that $\alpha$ has degree 2 over $\mathbb{Q}$, then the degree of $\alpha$ over $K$ is at most 2, hence $[E:K]\leq 2$ and $[E:\mathbb{Q}]=[E:K][K:\mathbb{Q}]=6$ or $12$.
$\bullet$ If $[E:\mathbb{Q}]=6$, i.e. $\alpha\in K$, then $[E:F]=[E:\mathbb{Q}]/[F:\mathbb{Q}]=3$, hence $\mathrm{Gal}(E/F)$ is a subgroup of $S_{3}$ with order 3, it must be $A_{3}$.
$\bullet$ If $[E:\mathbb{Q}]=12$, i.e. $\alpha\notin K$, then $[E:F]=[E:\mathbb{Q}]/[F:\mathbb{Q}]=6$, hence $\mathrm{Gal}(E/F)$ is a subgroup of $S_{3}$ with order 6. Now $\mathrm{Gal}(E/F)=S_{3}$.
Is the above solution correct?

The last point is not entirely clear.

$Gal(E/F)$ is a subgroup of $S_3$ with order $6$.

You only determined that $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})=S_3,$ but $Gal(E/F)$ is a subgroup of $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q}),$ not of $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}),$ and you didn't determine the former which is a group of order $12.$
Instead you can use the isomorphisms
$$Gal(E/F)=Gal(K\cdot F/F)=Gal(K/K\cap F)=Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}).$$
where the isomorphism in the middle is a theorem for general Galois extensions, and we have $K\cap F=\mathbb{Q}$ since $F$ is degree $2$ but is not contained in $K.$
